# PHP & XML parsing

Tags: php, xml

I have searched everything on google and still i cant seems to find a solution for this. Basically im helping my friend to create a php frontend for his ftp.

The ftp details are saved in xml. So i have to parse it to a php.

```
<FileZillaServer>
<Users>
<User Name="anonymous">
<Option Name="Pass">aaaaaa</Option>
<Option Name="Group"/>
<Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
<Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
<Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
<Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
<Option Name="Comments"/>
<Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
<IpFilter>
<Disallowed/>
<Allowed/>
</IpFilter>
<Permissions>
<Permission Dir="C:\xampp\anonymous">
<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
<Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>
<Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>
<Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>
<Option Name="DirCreate">0</Option>
<Option Name="DirDelete">0</Option>
<Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
<Option Name="DirSubdirs">0</Option>
<Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>
<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
</Permission>
<Permission Dir="C:\xampp\anonymous\incoming">
<Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
<Option Name="FileWrite">1</Option>
<Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>
<Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>
<Option Name="DirCreate">0</Option>
<Option Name="DirDelete">0</Option>
<Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
<Option Name="DirSubdirs">0</Option>
<Option Name="IsHome">0</Option>
<Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
</Permission>
</Permissions>
<SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">
<Download/>
<Upload/>
</SpeedLimits>
</User>
</Users>
</FileZillaServer>
```

Basically above is a sample content from XML. I need to know how to parse the content and display in PHP.

Just to display Name and pass.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

There are several PHP XML handling modules that you can use.  [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) is a good one if you are dealing with valid XML, which you appear to be.

The following code will parse your document and output the user name and password found within each `<User>` tag.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('test.xml');
$userNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Users');
foreach($userNodes as $user) {
  foreach($user->childNodes as $userData) {
    if ($userData->nodeName == 'User') {
      echo "User name: ";
      echo $userData->attributes->getNamedItem('Name')->nodeValue;
      foreach($userData->childNodes as $n) {
        if ($n->nodeName == 'Option' && $n->attributes->getNamedItem('Name')->nodeValue == 'Pass') {
          echo " Password: ".$n->nodeValue."\n";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml = "your xml string";
$xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

or

```
$xml_file = "path/to/file";
$xml_object = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
```

Read up on accessing the data through the resulting XML Object here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple code to extract your values.

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('xml.xml'));

//now extract all the variables are extracted below
$i = 0;

foreach($xml->Users->User as $key=>$myuser) {
    echo 'Name: '.$myuser->Name.'<br />';
}
```